# Cannot convert ('AnyObject?, NSError? -> Void' to 'CompletionBlock' (aka'(Optional<Any>, Optional<Error>) -> ()')

Tags: swift, xcode

```
fileprivate func playVideoId(_ apiId: String) {

    (MApi.sharedMApi() as! MApi).getVideoALaCarta(withID: apiId, completionHandler: { [weak self] (videoObject: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil || (videoObject) == nil) {
            print("ERROR AL DESCARGAR VIDEO A LA CARTA: \(String(describing: error))")
            self?.userInterface?.showLoadingView(false)
        } else {
            self?.userInterface?.presentPlayer(videoObject as! MApi_VideoAlaCarta)
        }
        } as CompletionBlock)
}
```

And the CompletionBlock code:

`$` typedef void (^CompletionBlock) (id object, NSError *error);

Comment: What version of Swift are you using ? Swift 3, right? If I remember well my Swift readings, prefer `Any` to `AnyObject` in Swift 3, and `Error` to `NSError`, as the error suggest.

Comment: Thanks, it works.